# Redirect for member pages

Tags: seo

I have member only pages on my site. If the user is not logged in, I have two options:

1. Show the login page directly at http://www.yoursite.com/member-only-page
2. Redirect the user to http://www.yoursite.com/login and after login, redirect back.

Which would be better from SEO point of view? What is the redirection type I should use? 301 is permanent?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`301` is the best header to return for permanent redirect.

Nevertheless, you do not have to worry about login pages. Google recommendation is to spot them as `no index, no follow`.